# How does one script the Keychain via rb-appscript?

Tags: ruby, applescript, keychain, rb-appscript

I followed the docs and wrote:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'appscript'

loginKeychain = Appscript::app('Keychain Scripting').keychains['login.keychain']
userName = loginKeychain.keys[its.name.eq(name)].password.get
```

**UPDATE:** if I run the script via Terminal, it succeeds the first time, and then returns the error below until I quit and restart Terminal; and repeat...

Error returned intermittently:

```
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rb-appscript-0.5.3/lib/appscript.rb:539:in `_send_command': CommandError (Appscript::CommandError)
        OSERROR: -600
        MESSAGE: Application isn't running.
        COMMAND: app("/System/Library/ScriptingAdditions/Keychain Scripting.app").keychains["login.keychain"].keys[its.name.eq("a name")].password.get()
```

**UPDATE 2:** Due to the mysterious error, and that Keychain Scripting seems buggy in general, I decided to use [MacRuby](http://www.macruby.org/). I found the [MacRuby Keychain Wrapper](https://github.com/ashchan/macruby-keychain-wrapper) library, which calls [Keychain Services](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/OSX_Technology_Overview/AppTechnology/AppTechnology.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001067-CH270-TPXREF132) directly, rather than going through Scripting:

```
require 'keychain-wrapper/keychain'
MRKeychain::GenericItem.item_for_service(service_name).password
```

- Easy
- More efficient
- Works flawlessly

Done.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't use Ruby but I used Python and I have no trouble.  I'd try doing regular Applescript and seeing if it can access Keychain Scripting.  If not then try rebooting your Mac.  But this sounds like more a problem of your computer than Appscript.

Comment: You successfully scripted Keychain using Python? Applescript worked fine from the AppleScript Editor - I prototyped it there before translating to Ruby.

Comment: Yeah - I ran a small test with Python & Appscript.  Try using ASTranslate and click the check to send the actual events to the application.  Sorry I can't help directly with Ruby.  I'm a Python man and just don't know Ruby.

Comment: How did you run your Python script? In Terminal, the same thing happened when I executed:
<pre>
    $python
    >>>from appscript import *
    >>>app('Keychain Scripting').keychains['login.keychain'].keys[its.name == 'name'].password.get()
</pre>

Comment: I ran it from within Textmate.  But that shouldn't matter.  Sounds like your appscript might be borked.  Try reinstalling.

Answer (score 0):

I'm getting that same error, but just with things that require authentification:

```
kc = app("Keychain Scripting").keychains["login.keychain"]
p kc.keys[its.name.eq("loginwindow")].name.get
# ["loginwindow"]
p kc.keys[its.name.eq("loginwindow")].password.get
# ... Application isn't running ...
```

`tell app "Keychain Scripting" to password of keys of keychain "login.keychain" where name is "loginwindow"` works just fine.